# A faster way to do numbering

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance, numbers

A few times I need to number or re-number a long list of items and find myself editing them line by line manually, is there a better way to do it? Any software/plugins or method to do it quickly? I'm not referring to `<ol>`, but editing the numbers within a line of text. for example

```
<div class="RandomExample">item 1 lorem ipsum</div>
<div class="RandomExample">item 2 lorem ipsum</div>
<div class="RandomExample">item 3 lorem ipsum</div>
<div class="RandomExample">item 4 lorem ipsum</div>
.. ..
.. .. 

/* the list go as long as it can take*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?
[Repl Example](https://repl.it/repls/PettyBleakHypertalk)

```
let string = ''
for(let i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
  string += `<div class="randomExample">item ${i} lorem ipsum</div>\n`
}
console.log(string)
```

Then you can copy it from the console and paste it.

Otherwise, you can structure the code on your page to generate the elements for you...

[Repl Example](https://repl.it/repls/LimeBurdensomeFlatassembler)

```
const parentDiv = document.querySelector('.parent')
for(let i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
  let childDiv = document.createElement('div')
  childDiv.classList.add('randomExample')
  childDiv.innerHTML = `item ${i} lorem ipsum`
  parentDiv.appendChild(childDiv)
}
```